# How to center 4 absolute-divs (balls) in the middle of my screen?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a loading-screen effect for my current assignment.

It requires us to create a `<div class="overlay">` with `position: fixed`. This funds as the background. Withing this div, there are 4 `<div class="circle">` with `position: absolute`.

We have to center these using absolute-position and `transform: translate`. and each ball has a margin of `80px` inbetween them

**Here is an image of an example I try to re-create**

[image: Example of what I try to create]

I have managed so far to perfectly-center the balls, but cause of the `position: absolute` they all overlap. How can I make sure I can get all 4 balls like in the picture?

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  z-index: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.overlay {
  background-color: #0d1133;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.circle {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#yellow {
  background-color: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(248, 255, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 145, 0, 1) 50%, rgba(255, 145, 0, 1) 100%);
}

#red {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255, 0, 215, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 0, 61, 1) 50%, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
}

#blue {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0, 255, 243, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 224, 255, 1) 50%, rgba(0, 185, 255, 1) 100%);
}

#purple {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255, 0, 241, 1) 0%, rgba(222, 0, 255, 1) 50%, rgba(157, 0, 255, 1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<main>

  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="circle" id="yellow"></div>
    <div class="circle" id="red"></div>
    <div class="circle" id="blue"> </div>
    <div class="circle" id="purple"></div>
  </div>

</main>
```

Comment: I'd put them inside of of their own `div` inside of `.overlay`. Then you can space them out how you want inside of that `div` and then center that `div`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with flexboxes, but if you need to animate them using `transform: translate` you can position them using:

`transform: translate(calc(-50% + <OFFSET>px), -50%)`

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  z-index: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.overlay {
  background-color: #0d1133;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.circle {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#yellow {
  background-color: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(248, 255, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 145, 0, 1) 50%, rgba(255, 145, 0, 1) 100%);
  transform: translate(calc(-50% - 240px), -50%);
}

#red {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255, 0, 215, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 0, 61, 1) 50%, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
  transform: translate(calc(-50% - 80px), -50%);
}

#blue {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0, 255, 243, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 224, 255, 1) 50%, rgba(0, 185, 255, 1) 100%);
  transform: translate(calc(-50% + 80px), -50%);
}

#purple {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255, 0, 241, 1) 0%, rgba(222, 0, 255, 1) 50%, rgba(157, 0, 255, 1) 100%);
  transform: translate(calc(-50% + 240px), -50%);
}
```

```html
<main>

  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="circle" id="yellow"></div>
    <div class="circle" id="red"></div>
    <div class="circle" id="blue"> </div>
    <div class="circle" id="purple"></div>
  </div>

</main>
```

Comment: That's what did it for me! All answers in given here would fix my issue, but this was the fix that would fit the assignment :)

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap them inside a `wrapper` class and position that `div` absolute (like you did for each ball).

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  z-index: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.overlay {
  background-color: #0d1133;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

.circle {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 40px;
}

#yellow {
  background-color: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(248, 255, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 145, 0, 1) 50%, rgba(255, 145, 0, 1) 100%);
}

#red {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255, 0, 215, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 0, 61, 1) 50%, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
}

#blue {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0, 255, 243, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 224, 255, 1) 50%, rgba(0, 185, 255, 1) 100%);
}

#purple {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255, 0, 241, 1) 0%, rgba(222, 0, 255, 1) 50%, rgba(157, 0, 255, 1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<main>

  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="circle" id="yellow"></div>
      <div class="circle" id="red"></div>
      <div class="circle" id="blue"> </div>
      <div class="circle" id="purple"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</main>
```

Comment: this breaks the circles into two rows on a smal screen

Comment: @DigitalJedi I know, but this is according to the assignment. Normally I would really prefer using `display: flex;` over `position: absolute`

Comment: @Roy Hey, thanks for the comment. I want to say the following: How can this be done without the usage of the extra `<div class="wrapper">` to put them in? IF that is possible of course without too much hassle.

I am not sure if my assignment "allows" me to add an extra layer to what I have already done (So `. overlay` and the 4 divs inside of it). However, I am not sure if this is the case of course

Answer (score 1):

You could use display: flex, aswell as align-items and justify content on the parent like so :

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  z-index: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.overlay {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #0d1133;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.circle {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 40px;
}

#yellow {
  background-color: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(248, 255, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 145, 0, 1) 50%, rgba(255, 145, 0, 1) 100%);
}

#red {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255, 0, 215, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 0, 61, 1) 50%, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
}

#blue {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0, 255, 243, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 224, 255, 1) 50%, rgba(0, 185, 255, 1) 100%);
}

#purple {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255, 0, 241, 1) 0%, rgba(222, 0, 255, 1) 50%, rgba(157, 0, 255, 1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<main>

  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="circle" id="yellow"></div>
    <div class="circle" id="red"></div>
    <div class="circle" id="blue"> </div>
    <div class="circle" id="purple"></div>
  </div>

</main>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, for my assignment that is, I am not "allowed to use" display flex.  Basically `position: absolute` and `transform: translte` are the 2 guidelines I have to work with, haha.

Answer (score 1):

Add an absolutely-positioned `div` container around the circles, and centre this on the page.

Then put the circles inside it (no longer absolutely-positioned) and give them a margin.

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  z-index: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.overlay {
  background-color: #0d1133;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.circles-container {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.circle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 40px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#yellow {
  background-color: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(248, 255, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 145, 0, 1) 50%, rgba(255, 145, 0, 1) 100%);
}

#red {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255, 0, 215, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 0, 61, 1) 50%, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
}

#blue {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0, 255, 243, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 224, 255, 1) 50%, rgba(0, 185, 255, 1) 100%);
}

#purple {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255, 0, 241, 1) 0%, rgba(222, 0, 255, 1) 50%, rgba(157, 0, 255, 1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<main>

  <div class="overlay">

    <div class="circles-container">
      <div class="circle" id="yellow"></div>
      <div class="circle" id="red"></div>
      <div class="circle" id="blue"> </div>
      <div class="circle" id="purple"></div>
    </div>

  </div>

</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is perfect and clean code using css flex

Html Code:

```
    <div class="circles-container">
      <div class="circle" id="red"></div>
      <div class="circle" id="orange"></div>
      <div class="circle" id="green"> </div>
      <div class="circle" id="purple"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Css Code:

```
.main-div{
  width:100%;
  height:-webkit-fill-available;
  display:flex;
  background: navy;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.circle{
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  border-radius:50px;
  display:inline-block;
}
#red{
  background:red
}
#orange{
  background:orange;
}
#green{
  background:green;
}
#purple{
  background:purple;
}
```